# clipping the mesh against user defined region

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am implementing clipping algorithm for a mesh where clipping region is a rectangle in normalized space [-1 , 1]. 
So my algorithm is as follows:

1. Create bounding box of a region to be used for a clipping, these coordinates will be in normalized space.
2. Create bounding box of a mesh in local space. transform them to clip coordinate space using MVP matrix. Divide by w to transform them into normalized space.

   ```
   vec4 transformed_coords = MVP * vec4(vertex,1.0);
   transformed_coords.xyz /= transformed_coords.w;
   ```
3. Check whether the two rectangles overlap or not. Use only x-y coordinates.

With this algorithm I am getting incorrect output.

```
model matrix
  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.000000 -1.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000

view * projection
  0.920664 -0.285565 -0.266194 -0.266141
  0.039495  0.746434 -0.664418 -0.664286
 -0.388354 -0.601072 -0.698633 -0.698493
 -0.063192 -1.194295  0.894055  1.093857

MVP matrix 
  0.920664 -0.285565 -0.266194 -0.266141
  0.388354  0.601072  0.698633  0.698493
  0.039495  0.746434 -0.664418 -0.664286
 -0.063192 -1.194295  0.894055  1.093857

bounding box in object space
  -23.376505 -23.376505 -0.023644
   23.376505 -23.376505 -0.023644
  -23.376505  23.376505 -0.023644
   23.376505  23.376505 -0.023644
  -23.376505 -23.376505  1.430214
   23.376505 -23.376505  1.430214
  -23.376505  23.376505  1.430214
   23.376505  23.376505  1.430214

after transformation with MVP
  -30.664371  -8.587399  -9.199142  -8.997323
   12.379420 -21.938423 -21.644522 -21.440216
  -12.507672  19.514534  23.464052  23.659344
   30.536121   6.163512  11.018670  11.216449
  -30.606953  -7.502190 -10.165111  -9.963099
   12.436841 -20.853212 -22.610493 -22.405994
  -12.450252  20.599745  22.498081  22.693565
   30.593540   7.248722  10.052701  10.250672

 the bounding box after MinMax NDC min -0.577393 0.549507 1.000000 max 3.408166 1.023237 1.000000 
 after NDC 
   3.408166 0.954439 1.022431 1.000000
  -0.577393 1.023237 1.009529 1.000000
  -0.528657 0.824813 0.991746 1.000000
   2.722441 0.549507 0.982367 1.000000
   3.072031 0.752998 1.020276 1.000000
  -0.555068 0.930698 1.009127 1.000000
  -0.548625 0.907735 0.991386 1.000000
   2.984540 0.707146 0.980687 1.000000

.min -0.577393 0.549507 max 3.408166 1.023237
```

Whereas min and max corner for region is min: -0.53, -0.53 max: 0.53, 0.53.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: I don't get why there is request for closing. Its graphics related problem with algorithm clearly mentioned.

Comment: Why is the last element of the diagonal view matrix different of 1? 1.09 is very strange. And are your multiplication order correct? projection * view != view * projection

Comment: my final mvp matrix is correct as I use the same matrix for the rendering on GPU which draws it perfectly. I think that my method of calculating NDC is incorrect.

Comment: I dont know, if i quite get your approach, but it seems complicated. What you could do is draw a quad on the stencil buffer, where you want to render and set the stencil operation.
Then you can simply render your world as normal and get the same effect. You can check out the following link for an working example:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer